# Python: parsing json file only where file doesn't start with a comma

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file which is not in the correct format. (I think?) So I have these blocks of json, but in between there is a comma as you can see in the code below. `,{`.

How can I parse this file, and extract only the json part, excluding the commas?

```
{
 "maps":[
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"},
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"}
        ],
"masks":
         {"id":"valore"},
"om_points":"value",
"parameters":
         {"id":"valore"}
}
,{
  "maps":[
          {"id":"blabla", "iscategorical":"0"},
          {"id":"blabla", "iscategorical":"0"}
         ],
  "masks":
           {"id":"valore"},
  "om_points":"value",
  "parameters":
               {"id":"valore"}
}
```

Comment: Prepend a `[` and append a `]`, then this should be valid JSON and can be parsed using a normal JSOn parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file as a string and wrap it into `[..]` to make a valid json.

```
import json

with open(fname, 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read()
data = json.loads("["+text+"]")
```

Now `data` would contain a list of your json objects.